# If model change the data , will the state be changed?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

1. model data:

```
<input v-model="title" type="text"/>
```

2. manage the "title" state through vuex

```
const state = {
    title: 'default title'
}

const getters = {
    title: state => state.title
}

const mutations = {
    setTitle: (state, payload) => (state.title = payload.title)
}
```

3. If I change the text in the input, will the title be changed automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`If I change the text in the input, will the title be changed automatically?`

**No.** You need to call some [action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html), which will call some [mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) and update vuex's state.

Take a look at the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

By the way, your getter will always return `undefined` because there is no field called count in your state.

It should be:

```
const getters = {
    title: state => state.title
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, I see the difference between action and mutation. Because there is no asynchronous operation about changing the title, I can update the state just through mutation instead of action. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, you can. But I think you don't should do it always. For example, if you want to process the data before update state, call a service or call other functions, it would be safer do it in actions, once mutations should only *mutate* the state. That's how I work. Hope it helps!